# Looking for an example of a norm's kernel that is not an ideal

Tags: ring-theory

In order to formulate the question we need a couple of notions.
(All rings mentioned are unital and nonzero, all modules are unitary.)

Let $k$ be a ring, $A$ a $k$-module,
and $f\colon A\to S$ a function from the module $A$ to a set $S$.
We say that $f$ **does not depend on a submodule** $W$ **of** $A$
if $f(a+w)=f(a)$ for all $a\in A$ and all $w\in W$.
The **kernel of** $f$ is defined as the subset $\ker_k(f)$ of $A$
consisting of all $z\in A$
such that $f(a+\lambda z)=f(a)$ for all $a\in A$ and all $\lambda\in k\,$;
$\ker_k(f)$ is the largest submodule of $A$ on which $f$ does not depend.
In case when $A$ is just an abelian (additive) group (a $\mathbb{Z}$-module),
the kernel of $f$ is
$\ker_{\mathbb{Z}}(f)=\{z\in A\mid\text{$f(a+z)=f(a)$ for all $a\in A$}\}$.

We say that a ring $R$ is spanned by units
if every element of $R$ is a sum of units of $R$.

Now consider the following lemma:

> Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ a (multiplicatively written) monoid,
>   and $N\colon R\to M$ a homomorphism of multiplicative monoids.
>   If $R$ is spanned by units,
>   then $\ker_{\mathbb{Z}}(N)$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$.

**Proof.** $~$We know that $Z:=\ker_{\mathbb{Z}}(N)$
is a subgroup of the additive group $R$.
Let $z\in Z$.
If $u$ is a unit of $R$ and $r\in R$,
then $N(r+uz)=N(u)N(u^{-1}r+z)=N(u)N(u^{-1}r)=N(r)$, thus $uz\in Z$;
since $R$ is spanned by units, we have $sz\in Z$ for every $s\in R$.
Similarly we prove that $zs\in Z$ for every $s\in R$.$~$ **Done.**

**Question(s).** $~$After proving the lemma,
I naturally wanted to check that the condition that $R$ be spanned by units
cannot be omitted.
However, for the life of me I am unable to find an example of $R$, $M$, $N$
as in the first statement of the lemma,
but with the ring $R$ not spanned by units
and with $\ker_{\mathbb{Z}}(R)$ not an ideal of $R$.
Can you help me out here, one way or another -- either by finding an example
demonstrating that the condition that $R$ is spanned by units cannot be omitted,
or by coming up with a proof which does not need the condition?
Perhaps the condition can be replaced by some weaker condition?

**Remarks.** $~$The lemma above is just a fragment of a wider story.
For one thing, the lemma can be augmented by the following statement:

> With everything as in the lemma,
>   if $N$ has the additional property that for every $r\in R$,
>   $N(r)$ invertible in $M$ implies $r$ invertible in $R$,
>   then the ideal $\ker_{\mathbb{Z}}(N)$ is contained in the Jacobson radical of $R$.

**Proof.** $~$For every $z\in\ker_{\mathbb{Z}}(N)$,
$N(1+z)=N(1)=1$ is invertible, thus $1+z$ is a unit.$~$ **Done.**

In certain interesting situations the kernel of $N$ *is* the Jacobson radical $J$ of $R$.
In such a case $N$ factors through the natural projection $p\colon R\to R/J$
as $N=\overline{N}\circ p$, where the (unique) function $\overline{N}\colon R/J\to M$
is a homomorphism of multiplicative monoids, and $R/J$ is Jacobson-semisimple.

Comment: Hmm, how would one show these kernels are even additively closed?

Comment: Elementary, my dear Watson. If $f(a+\lambda x)=f(a)$ and $f(a+\lambda y)=f(a)$ for all $a\in A$ and $\lambda\in k$, then $f(a+\lambda(x+y))=f((a+\lambda x)+\lambda y)=f(a+\lambda x)=f(a)$ for all $a\in A$ and $\lambda\in k$. Also, if $f(a+\lambda x)=f(a)$ for all $a\in A$ and $\lambda\in k$, and $\mu\in k$, then $f(a+\lambda(\mu x))=f(a+(\lambda\mu)x)=f(a)$ for all $a\in A$ and $\lambda\in k$. Thus $\ker_k(f)$ is a submodule of $A$. Clearly $f$ does not depend on $\ker_k(f)$, and it is easy to check that if $W$ is a submodule on which $f$ does not depend, then $W$ is contained in $\ker_k(f)$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I keep forgetting this is about the right hand term and not the $a$.

Comment: How these kernels relate to the 'known' kernels. If $f$ is a linear map between $k$-modules, then $\ker_k(f)$ is the usual kernel of $f$. If $q\colon V\to F$ is a quadratic form on a vector space $V$ over a field $F$, then $\ker_F(q)$ is sometimes known as the kernel, and sometimes as the radical, of $q$. If $A$, $B$, $C$ are $k$-modules and $g\colon A\times B\to C$ is a bilinear map with the left kernel $X$ and the right kernel $Y$, then $\ker_k(g)=X\times Y$. I do not know whether somebody had already defined such general kernels. I find them extremely useful.

Comment: Correction: in the example of a bilinear $g$ in the preceding note the base ring $k$ is supposed to be commutative.

Comment: Another look at the kernel. The additive group of the module $A$ acts by translations $T_x$ on functions $f\in S^A$, where $(T_xf)(a)=f(a-x)$ for $a\in A$. Let $\mathrm{stab}_T(f)=\{x\in A\mid T_xf=f\}$ be the stabilizer subgroup of $f$ for the action $T$; then $\ker_k(f)=\{z\in A\mid kz\subseteq \mathrm{stab}_T(f)\}$.